# How to get List<Model> Object in HTTP POST

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two model classes:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
public class GroupModel
{
    public Guid Id { get;  set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I created a View (Create.Aspx) by inheriting GroupModel class.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyApp.Models.GroupModel>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is generating only two fields (Id, Name) in my aspx view. Also I am able to get the form data in the Model class object in ё[HttpPost]ё request which contains the data for ID and NAME field in controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(GroupModel groupModel)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

How can I get the data in `List<UserModel>` object ?

I am thinking to Put a List control with checkboxes containing Users. Then catch them using `FormCollection` object in controller.

Please suggest if I am in correct way or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/UserModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<YourApp.Models.UserModel>" %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id) %>

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress) %>

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoginName) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginName) %>
...
```

And then inside the main view you could include this editor template:

```
...
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Users) %>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

This will invoke the editor template for each item in the `Users` collection. So you could fill this collection in your GET action with some users and you will be able to edit their information inside the form.